# Get number of lines and columns of command window using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a question regarding the MODE batch command.

The following code allows me to resize the console window to 10 lines of 200 characters.

```
mode con cols=200 lines=10
```

Is there also a way to read out the currently set number of lines and columns?

So, for the example above *col=200* and *lines=10* should be returned.

Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything on your own so far? if not: a good starting point is `for` with the `/F` syntax for parsing the output of a command -- type `for /?`; remember that SO is not a coding service... thank you!

Comment: try `mode` without parameters. Parse the Output with `for` (as aschimpfl already suggested)

Comment: I am not a batch specialist. I have searched the internet and the batch documentation quite long and found nothing useful. I will try what you have suggested. Only startings mode was a good hint because it seems to contain the relevant information. So parsing it may really lead to the solution. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your Code in steps:

a) use `mode` to get the desired data.

```
mode
```

a1) get output for desired device only:

```
mode con
```

b) filter for "columns" and "lines" to get rid of unwanted Information:

```
mode con|findstr "Zeilen Spalten"
```

c) use `for /f` to parse the Output of a command and set the variables. Look at the structure of the Output and find suitable Tokens and delimiters:

```
for /f "Tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('mode con^|findstr "Zeilen Spalten"') do set %%a=%%b
```

Adapt "Zeilen" and "Spalten" to your Output of `mode` (language dependent)

```
C:\>mode con

Status von Gerät CON:
---------------------
    Zeilen:          300
    Spalten:         120
    Wiederholrate:   31
    Verzögerungszeit:1
    Codepage:        850


C:\>for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %a in ('mode con^|findstr "Zeilen Spalten"') do @echo set %a=%b
set Zeilen=300
set Spalten=120

C:\>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: just tried on another computer. Replace `mode` with `mode con` to get output only for console device (terminal). (None of _my_ devices except console lists lines or colums, but who knows - better be precise)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little batch file that returns the number of lines and columns and stores their values to `%LINES%` and `%COLS%`, respectively. Opposed to @Stephan's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32393252/5047996) providing a one-liner for being typed directly in the command prompt, this script does not depend on the system language):

```
@echo off

set LINES=
set COLS=
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=: " %%L in (
  'mode CON:'
) do (
  if defined LINES (
    set COLS=%%L
    goto :QUIT
  ) else (
    set LINES=%%L
  )
)
:QUIT
echo %LINES% lines, %COLS% columns
```

Answer (score 1):

This method should work in any locale (not language dependent):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "lines="
set "cols="
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('mode con') do for %%b in (%%a) do (
   if not defined lines (
      set "lines=%%b"
   ) else if not defined cols (
      set "cols=%%b"
   )
)
echo cols=%cols% lines=%lines%
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget /a parameter to skip previous spaces and get the number

```
set "_LINES="
set "_COLS="

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('mode con') do (
    echo Second token: %%a
    if defined _LINES (
        set /a "_COLS=%%a"
        goto END_MODE_CON
    ) else (
        set /a _LINES=%%a
    )
)

:END_MODE_CON
echo Lines: %_LINES%, columns: %_COLS%
```