# Extract value from spring boot prometheus with windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, prometheus

I use spring boot with prometheus metrics endpoint and i like to achieve the following under microsoft windows cmd (with linux it would not be a problem for me)

write a small batch script which

- download prometheus endpoint - it worked with `curl -s http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus`
- extract the metric I am interested in which is system_cpu_usage - which works if I pipe the curl output to findstr like this `curl -s http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus | findstr "^system_cpu_usage"`
- remove the system_cpu_usage from the output so that I only have the value of the metric

- no idea how to achieve it tools like awk, cut, sed are not existing under windows :-(

example:
http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus returns (simplified )

```
#
system_cpu_usage 0.43242
other_metric 4.54
```

and i want to call the script which returns then `0.43242`

Thanks for some helpful ideas

Comment: usually, you use a `for /f` loop to catch the output of a command with proper tokens and delimiters. See `for /?`.

Comment: I did a detailed description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32393252/2152082), using another command.

Comment: You should clarify the actual output. Currently you show it as `#\system_cpu_usage 0.43242\n`, but also show the use of `findstr "^system_cpu_usage"`. The latter expects the line to begin with the string `system_cpu_usage`, yet you show it as beginning with `#`, (which doesn't match it). Also you need to clarify whether that is an actual string `\n`, or a representation of a new line, (Lf or CrLf).

Comment: sorry. one of my editingremoved the `\n` now i rewrote the output to look more like a textfile. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @Stephan - thanks you proposal worked. I forget to put the `^` in front of the `|` after I did this the script run. Thank you!

Comment: @EhmKaha.k.a.MichaelKrauße, if comments helped you to work out solution yourself, please consider posting an answer.